# Is there an add_days in ruby datetime?

Tags: ruby

In C#, There is a method AddDays([number of days]) in DateTime class.

Is there any kind of method like this in ruby?

Comment: use Rails... You can have something like this `t=Time.now; t + 3.days`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The `Date` class provides a `+` operator that does just that.

```
>> d = Date.today
=> #<Date: 4910149/2,0,2299161>
>> d.to_s
=> "2009-08-31"
>> (d+3).to_s
=> "2009-09-03"
>>
```

Answer (score 33):

In Rails there are very useful methods of `Fixnum` class for this (here `n` is `Fixnum`. For example: `1,2,3....` ):

```
Date.today + n.seconds # you can use 1.second
Date.today + n.minutes # you can use 1.minute
Date.today + n.hours # you can use 1.hour
Date.today + n.days # you can use 1.day
Date.today + n.weeks # you can use 1.week
Date.today + n.months # you can use 1.month
Date.today + n.years # you can use 1.year
```

These are convenient for `Time` class too.

PS: require *Active Support Core Extensions* to use these in Ruby

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

Comment: Those methods are Rails-specific

Comment: you can use active support without including the whole Rails framework:
`gem 'activesupport'`
`require 'active_support'`
`require 'active_support/core_ext'`

Answer (score 16):

I think `next_day` is more readable than `+` version.

```rb
require 'date'

DateTime.new(2016,5,17)
# => #<DateTime: 2016-05-17T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457526j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.new(2016,5,17).next_day(10)
# => #<DateTime: 2016-05-27T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457536j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.new(2016,5,17)
# => #<Date: 2016-05-17 ((2457526j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.new(2016,5,17).next_day(10)
# => #<Date: 2016-05-27 ((2457536j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_day.

Answer (score 14):

From the [Date class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000385):

> *+(n)*
>
> Return a new Date object that is n days later than the current one.
>
> n may be a negative value, in which case the new Date is earlier than the current one; however, #-() might be more intuitive.
>
> If n is not a Numeric, a TypeError will be thrown. In particular, two Dates cannot be added to each other.

Answer (score 5):

```
Date.new(2001,9,01).next_day(30) # 30 - numbers of day 
# => #<Date: 2001-10-01 ...
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `advance` (https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/advance) method. I think it's more legible.

```
date = Date.today
# => Fri, 25 Oct 2019
date.advance(days: 10)
# => Mon, 04 Nov 2019

time = DateTime.now
# => Fri, 25 Oct 2019 14:32:53 +0200
time.advance(months:1, weeks: 2, days: 2, hours: 6, minutes: 6, seconds: 34)
# => Wed, 11 Dec 2019 20:39:27 +0200
```