# How to add x days to a date in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to add `x` days to a date input in ruby.

For example, my input is `15-09-2014 17:16`, and the script needs to add 10 days to it.

So the output becomes `25-09-2014 17:16`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Date.today + 10.days is only in rails?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to parse and adjust that:

```
require 'date'
parsed = DateTime.strptime('15-09-2014 17:16', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

parsed.next_day(10).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
# => "25-09-2014 17:16"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a + operator that you can use on Dates.  Check out this solution:

[Is there an add_days in ruby datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356457/is-there-an-add-days-in-ruby-datetime)